# Transfer Scrumwise to GreenHopper

Tags: import, export, agile, jira-agile

Scrumwise can export its whole data as XML. This contains lots of data including Projects, Backlog, Sprints, Tasks, Team Members, etc. It can also export Tasks as CSV.

GreenHopper can import Projects in various formats (but not XML).

I'd like to transfer as much as possible between Scrumwise and GreenHopper. I'm thinking of extracting the Projects node from the XML, converting to JSON, and importing that. Right now GreenHopper rejects the data right from the start.

Is there a reference to the data schema used in GreenHopper? I'd like to transfer more than just the Project, but all its associated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all the backlog tasks and export. Scrumwise uses the semicolon as the delimiter. Convert by search and replace and JIRA will at least try to import. Import into a new empty project, expect it to take several attempts to get it right. You'll need to add columns for time remaining in seconds. Getting the statuses and resolution was the hardest part. JIRA gives you status options that will fail during import! Check the jira workflow for valid states. Also, an empty resolution means "unresolved", an unrecognized resolution defaults to "resolved". For tasks, you will need to export as XML, parse the XML for all tasks and add a parent ID column.